# Why i can not use Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION_VECTOR. Type is not recognised

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors

The problem is, that this sensors should be available:

- int TYPE_ACCELEROMETER
- int TYPE_ALL
- int **TYPE_GRAVITY**
- int TYPE_GYROSCOPE
- int TYPE_LIGHT
- int ***TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION***
- int TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD
- int TYPE_ORIENTATION
- int TYPE_PRESSURE
- int TYPE_PROXIMITY
- int **TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR**
- int TYPE_TEMPERATURE

Why are these three disabled? They are not recognised..."TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Only these are recognised:

- int TYPE_ACCELEROMETER
- int TYPE_ALL
- int TYPE_GYROSCOPE
- int TYPE_LIGHT
- int TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD
- int TYPE_ORIENTATION
- int TYPE_PRESSURE
- int TYPE_PROXIMITY
- int TYPE_TEMPERATURE

code is:

```
        mRotationVectorSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(
                Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);
```

Project build target is 2.2, API 8.
Why i can not use TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR and other types?

Tnx for andswer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a sensor that is available only from API version 9 (you are using API version 8).
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR

Check the "Since API level ..." at the right of each method/field

Answer (score 0):

in Android 2.2, Gravity and linear Acceleration Vectors are not available...
Only for versions 2.3 (GingerBread) and newer...

Greetings Ralf